# Modal is displayed below the items

Tags: reactjs, sass, z-index, simplemodal

I have come into a strange issue that has stopped me for a few hours. I have created a MERN app in which I have a page that I introduce members of a team. I also have a modal for each member triggered by click on member. The problem is that when I create a new member, the modals related to previous members is displayed behind the latter added members. I will attach pictures to more clearly demonstrate what happens.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4acyu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRZF4.png)

Here is how I have defined the modal:

```
const Modal = ({ closeModal, children }) => {
  const closeIcon = () => (
    <FontAwesome
      name='times'
      onClick={closeModal}
      className='modal-font-awesome'
    />
  )
  return (
    <div id='overlay'>
      <div className='content'>
        {closeIcon()}
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is my scss code for styling the modal:

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.content {
  margin: 120px auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  width: 70vw;
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 5px solid rgb(37, 153, 124);
}
```

Do you have any suggestions about what is happening?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe a redundant suggestion here but have you tried setting the `z-index` for `#overlay`?

Comment: @Danoram Yes, I did, and it didn't work unfortunately!